# Toggle Draggable divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, css-transitions

[Draggable divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs2Yv.png)

I wanted to implement the above toggle switching function and element should be draggable and clickable along with animation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post what you've tried and more details about what you mean about it being draggable? Draggable normally has to do with Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Downvoters: have mercy on newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle switch (on/off button) with CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```